# Trigonometric equations for three different regions on number line

Tags: trigonometry

> I have 
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}k\cot(sx),&x<pa<qa\\
> k\cot(s[x-b]),&x>qa>pa\end{cases}$$
>   I have to find $f(x)$ for $pa<x<qa$, given $s(a-b)=\pi$.

$p,q$ are any real nos.

Do I just say that $f(x)$ for this region is the same as equivalence of the two mentioned above?

$a$ is the length of the concerned complete region and $b$ is a constant whose value is defined from the above equation.

I also require the three functions to be continuous in [x, a]

Comment: If the question seems off topic, tell me to take it down.

Comment: $p,q$ are consecutive integers? Couldn't $f$ just be anything between $pa$ and $qa$? Is there some condition on $f$ you need to meet?

Comment: Yes@ Shubham Johri I require continuity and no p,q are real nos.